# How to mask a geotiff image with a binary image of different dimensions and spatial resolution?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mask, geotiff

I have two rasters in geotiff format where I would like to perform matrix multiplication to "mask out" areas in the b/w image that correspond to "0" values in the binary image.  The following describes the two raster datasets:

1. A b/w image at 1m spatial resolution (8-bit unsigned integer; 6190
   columns, 7750 rows)
2. A binary image (0 and 1) (2-bit unsigned integer; 8573 columns,
   11077 rows)

This screenshot shows image 2 overlaying image 1 and highlights the difference in pixel size

[image]

This is the incorrect result of my mask operation.  You can see that the mask image was shrunk to the extent of the b/w image, rather than maintaining their spatial dimensions.

[image]

**How can I perform a mask operation with geotiffs of different sizes and of different spatial resolution?**

---

This is the method I used to apply the mask:

```
image1 = 'c:\temp\image2.tif'

%get geotiff metrics
tiffdata = geotiffinfo(image1);
ncols = tiffdata.Width;
nrows = tiffdata.Height;

% Read mask
mask = 'X:\landsat_mask\raster_based\mask\mask_binary.tif';
[J, S] = geotiffread(mask);
mask = double(J);

% Apply binary mask
mask= imresize(mask,[nrows ncols]); %change the mask dimension similar to buffer image
masked = immultiply(double(Zval),mask);
masked =uint8(masked);

%Write Coords_ pixels to .tif   
outputdir = 'C:\temp\'
outfilename = [outputdir 'out' '.tif'];  
geotiffwrite(outfilename, masked, R, 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag', tiffdata.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag)
```